# In the Bloch representation why pre and post multiply by rotation operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

In [these notes](http://www.vcpc.univie.ac.at/~ian/hotlist/qc/talks/bloch-sphere-rotations.pdf) to see the effect of the rotation operator $R$, on slide 11, the calculation $\rho' = R\rho R^{\dagger}$ is performed. Why isn't the operator only applied to the state AS $\rho' = R\rho$?

Comment: The answer is essentially on page 9.